# Referring to an attached table's fields in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm creating a windows forms application to display all the data in my database.

So the database has a table called **Items**, a sub-table called **Tags**, and these two tables have a 1:M relationship. I can add a Linq-to-SQL class to my Project, then create a datagrid to access the main Items table without any problems.

Looking at the properties of the **Items class** that was created by Linq-to-SQL, I can see it has the **Tags** table attached to it (EntitySet), but I can't access any of the **Tags** fields! Is there some way to do this?

I want to create a new column in the datagrid, called TagsList, and for each Item, I want to display a concatenated list of all corresponding **Tags.Name**. I figured I could do something like adding a new property to the Items class as so:

```
public partial class Items
  {
    public string TagsList
      {
        return this.Tags.Name.Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y));
      }
  }
```

But obviously, this isn't working, because there is no definition for it. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `Items.Tags` is of type `ICollection<Tags>` (or `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`, I can't remember which linq-to-sql uses) as you state that `Items` and `Tags` have a one-to-many relationship. If this is not the case let me know and I'll delete or edit my answer as appropriate.

`Name` is a property on each individual `Tags` and not the collection which is why `Tags.Name` is incorrect.

Try the following:

```
return this.Tags.Select(tag => tag.Name).Aggregate((x, y) => x + ", " + y));
```

`Tags.Select(tag => tag.Name)` will return `IEnumerable<string>` of names and then you aggregate that.

Comment: You're right - the Select method does indeed get me the values I want, and I can aggregate the list of Name from it. Unfortunately, the results are produced incredibly slowly - a look at the SQL profiler indicates that executes a call to the database once for the main Items table, and the one call for EACH Items. There must be a more efficient way to do this from what I'm trying to achieve.